# Is there a way to filter the AWS Batch Jobs landing page with a URL parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

When you visit the AWS Batch Jobs list landing page (https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/batch/home?region=us-east-1#jobs), it requires that you select a queue, and then it shows all jobs. Is there a way to have this page automatically pick my main queue, and then filter out all jobs whose name includes the phrase "frequently"?

Ideally, I'd like to do this by passing URL query/hash parameters. If that's not possible, is there a Tampermonkey approach that can populate the queue and search fields?